# Is there a way to set a certain permission in "Facebook Login" process as "required"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

Is there a way to set a certain permission in "Facebook Login" process (such as "email" permission) as "required", so a user can only approve logging in with that permission or cancel (a.k.a close login popup)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the user approved the permissions right after login, with the `return_scopes` parameter: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

If he did not approve some permission, don't let him use the App or the specific part of the App.